# Why JRE with Liferay

Tags: liferay, java

I downloaded Liferay Tomcat bundle and I can see that there is a JRE inside TOMCAT_HOME. Why this JRE. The JRE is not present there if I download Tomcat from Apache website.

Any idea?

Comment: Do either of the below answer your question? If so please accept one of them to help other people who may have the same question. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JRE is included with Liferay bundle because it is designed to work out of the box with no need for user configuration (like installing Java and configuring Tomcat). It's also the JRE Liferay has been tested & built with.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know anything about Liferay specifically but there are a few reasons someone might want to control the JRE.

- They may only support a specific version.
- They may want their application to not have any dependencies making it easier to install
- They may want to enable unlimited strength JCE policy files.
- They may ship with endorsed libraries in the JRE to ensure that the newest versions of standard libraries are being used.

Comment: While the reasons in general are correct, in this case, the second item is the reason for bundling the JDK with Liferay to get started easily. It's a windows 32 bit JRE, so in production you probably want to have a different one. But it's fine for starting immediately: Unzip, run, evaluate.